# How to create new company file in QuickBooks Online Account

Tags: quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

In my application, I need to handle multiple company files. So my question is can we have multiple company file with one QuickBooks Online account? How can we create new company file in a existing QuickBooks Online Account?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do so, sign up for a free trial of QuickBooks Online at http://quickbooks.intuit.com using existing intuit id.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: In that way we are creating new online account. But I need to have one online account and multiple company file

Comment: Yes. Using single online account you can have multiple company files. Don't fill up all form values instead use 'Already have an Intuit user ID?'(as seen in the above snapshot) link and use your existing login credential.